# Parsing single json entry to multiple objects with Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a json response that looks like this:

```
{
    "id":"001",
    "name":"Name",
    "param_distance":"10",
    "param_sampling":"2"
}
```

And I have two classes: Teste and Parameters

```
public class Test {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Parameters params;
}

public class Parameters {
    private double distance;
    private int sampling;
}
```

My question is: is there a way to make Gson understand that some of the json attributes should go to the Parameters class, or the only way is to "manually" parse this ?

### EDIT

Well, just to make my comment in @MikO's answer more readable:

I'll add a list of an object to the json output, so json response should look like this:

```
  {
    "id":"001",
    "name":"Name",
    "param_distance":"10",
    "param_sampling":"2",
    "events":[
        {
            "id":"01",
            "value":"22.5"
        },
        {
            "id":"02",
            "value":"31.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the Deserializer class would look like this:

```
public class TestDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Test> {
    @Override
    public Test deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setId(obj.get("id").getAsInt());
        test.setName(obj.get("name").getAsString());        

        Parameters params = new Parameters();
        params.setDistance(obj.get("param_distance").getAsDouble());
        params.setSampling(obj.get("param_sampling").getAsInt());
        test.setParameters(params);

        Gson eventGson = new Gson();
        Type eventsType = new TypeToken<List<Event>>(){}.getType();
        List<Event> eventList = eventGson.fromJson(obj.get("events"), eventsType);
        test.setEvents(eventList);
        return test;
    }
}
```

And doing:

```
GsonBuilder gBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Test.class, new TestDeserializer());
Gson gson = gBuilder.create();
Test test = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
```

Gives me the test object the way I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to make Gson understand it is to write a custom deserializer by creating a `TypeAdapter` for your `Test` class. You can find information in [**Gson's User Guide**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer). It is not exactly a *manual parsing*, but it is not that different, since you have to tell Gson how to deal with each JSON value...

It should be something like this:

```
private class TestDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Test> {
  public Test deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

    int id = obj.get("id").getAsInt();
    String name = obj.get("name").getAsString();

    double distance = obj.get("param_distance").getAsDouble();
    int sampling = obj.get("param_sampling").getAsInt();

    //assuming you have suitable constructors...
    Test test = new Test(id, name, new Parameters(distance, sampling));

    return test;
  }
}
```

Then you have to register the `TypeAdapter` with:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Test.class, new TestDeserializer());
```

And finally you just have to parse your JSON as usual, with:

```
gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, Test.class);
```

Gson will automatically use your custom deserializer to parse your JSON into your `Test` class.

Comment: Yep. I've got lots of "examples" in some code I was playing around with at one point. Here's one class, but most everything in that directory has a custom adapter: https://github.com/chriskessel/MyHex/blob/master/src/kessel/hex/domain/Army.java

Comment: Ok. That worked. 

But Let's complicate a little bit the question. 

I have also a list in this Test class. List<Event>. How would I include this List parsing in this method. From what I read, I would have to use the JsonArray class, is that right ?

Comment: Ok. I got the Event List working too. You can get the element and use the regurlar Gson object to parse it. 

`Gson eventGson = new Gson();
  Type eventsType = new TypeToken<List<Event>>(){}.getType();
  List<Event> eventList = eventGson.fromJson(obj.get("events"), eventsType);
  test.setEvents(eventList);`
Json input would be something like: `{"id":"001","name":"Name","param_distance":"10","param_sampling":"2", "events":[{"id":"01"}, {"id":"02"}]}`

Comment: I've updated my question with this info. Thanks for the help... =)