# Deserialize json array to map using Gson

Tags: arrays, dictionary, gson

I have following structure in json.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "FieldMapName1",
      "Fields": [
      {
        "Name": "FieldName1",
        "Values": [
          {
            "ID": 1,
            "Value": "Value1"
          },
          // ...
        ]
      },
      // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

Is there a way to convert it to:

```
Map<String, FieldMap> fieldMap;
```

Each field map object contains:

```
Map<String, Field> fields;
```

And each Field:

```
Map<Integer, String> values;
```

Should I write custom deserializer or there is some better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to use `TypeToken`. Your structure can be expressed as (yep, the generic is ugly) :

```
 Type t= new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>>() {}.getType();
```

Then in the json, drop your fields for someting like :

```
{"FieldMapName1":{"FieldName1":{"1":"value1", ...}},...}
```

Then use it :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> map = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, t);
```

Comment: Then I don't think there is an easy way. You can find inspiration in `MapTypeAdapterFactory`

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't parse your JSON in the class structure you want to parse it, basically because your JSON doesn't represent that class structure...

Firstly, your whole JSON is surrounded by `[ ]`, so you can't parse it into any `Map`, since a `Map` is an object (surrounded by `{ }`), and the same happens with the other elements you want to transform into maps...

Your JSON element would be actually represented by this class structure:

```
List<FieldMap>

class FieldMap
  String Name
  List<Field> Fields

class Field
  String Name
  List<Value> Values

class Value
  int ID
  String Value
```

So you could either parse your JSON in this structure and then move the data to your class structure, or you will definitely have to write a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer)... You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680108/parsing-single-json-entry-to-multiple-objects-with-gson/17680814#17680814)... You can try, and if you have trouble creating it ask again...